# How to get values from a selected item in a listView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a onCreateContextMenu() to perform delete and Edit functions by taking values from a listview.In my code Delete function and edit funtions both are working well. But my problem is when ever I try to edit from the listview it is not passing values from what I selected. Always it passes the very first detail on my list view. At a similar kind of problem this was solved when I pass a value of a textview by using as "  TextView updateName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);". But at this point I'm unable to pass the "view" to retrive the specific value from the textview. How can I change this?

```
//creating the longtimeClicked bar when loading the app
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(" Unit Options");
     menu.add(Menu.NONE,EDIT,Menu.NONE, " Edit Unit");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, Menu.NONE, " Delete Unit");

}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case DELETE:


            dbHandler.deleteUnits(Unit.get(longClickedItemIndex));

            Unit.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
            unitsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unit has been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        case EDIT:

   TextView updateName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);
                    String updateName1 = updateName.getText().toString();
                    TextView updateBulb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLNoofBulbs);
                    //  String updateBulb1=updateBulb.getText().toString();
                    TextView updateFan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLNoOfFans);
                    //String updateFan1=updateFan.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent_valueUpdate = new Intent(CreateNewUnit.this,
                            UpdateUnit.class);

                    int updateBulb1 = Integer.valueOf(updateBulb.getText().toString());
                    int updateFan1 = Integer.valueOf(updateFan.getText().toString());
                    // intent_valueBulb.putExtra("KeyValueA",2);
                    intent_valueUpdate.putExtra("keyNameA", updateName1);
                    intent_valueUpdate.putExtra("keyBulb1", updateBulb1);
                    intent_valueUpdate.putExtra("keyFan1", updateFan1);
                    startActivity(intent_valueUpdate);


            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Is there a hit if you set a breakpoint in onContextItemSelected(), item.getItemId() specifically?

Answer (score 1):

According to Android documentation @ [Menu class](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), you need to call `registerForContextMenu` method, like in your `onCreate`(). Search text for "Creating a floating context menu". The context menu gets triggered on long-item clicks.
Sample code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   registerForContextMenu(listview);
...
}
```